# How to insert a third party API result into Wordpress page/content?

Tags: wordpress

I have a CURL method that we use for calling the third party API via GitBash:

```
curl -u "xxx@dxwxcxrp.com:hPhO4IXXXXXYM2zXXXXX" -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://dxwxcxrp.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/search?jql=created>=startOfMonth()&key=DCHC01&startAt=1&maxResults=1&fields=id,key"
```

The result will be like this:

```
{
   "expand":"names,schema",
   "startAt":1,
   "maxResults":1,
   "total":31,
   "issues":[
      {
         "expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
         "id":"28648",
         "self":"https://dxwxcxrp.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/28648",
         "key":"DCHC01-7059"
      }
   ]
}
```

How do we display this on Wordpress website? Do we need to create a plugin for this? Or is there any other method that is simple to implement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends where you want to display it, and (sometimes) how your site is built.  You could use [shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), which would only require a function (and register callback) in `functions.php`, or you could build a small plugin.  If you want it to run on every page load and you're not worried about API rate limits, the shortcode solution would probably be easiest to implement.

Modification of the sample linked to above:

```php
function startOfMonth()
{
    return 1;
}

// [dcpartners_json]
function dcpartners_json($atts)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $startOfMonth = startOfMonth();
    $auth = "xxx@dxwxcxrp.com:hPhO4IXXXXXYM2zXXXXX";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://dxwxcxrp.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/search?jql=created>=$startOfMonth&key=DCHC01&startAt=1&maxResults=1&fields=id,key");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close();

    return $json;
}

add_shortcode('dcpartners_json', 'dcpartners_json');
```

That would just spit out a JSON string, not HTML.

Comment: How do I use this? I assume I need to add the code: in /wp-includes/functions.php ? How come I got 500 HTTP error on the site ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed 2 semi-colons in that example above.  It's updated now.  You would add this to your theme's `functions.php` file, path will be something like `/wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/functions.php`.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is already giving you the opportunity to do this using the `wp-api`. 
 
I strongly encourage you to read more useful details for your project [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get).
I do believe that if you try to achieve a simple get request and want to handle it wordpress you should handle it the WP way. It will be far more simple to integrate the data the way you want next. (SQL tables, plugins, raw call on custom template..)

## Practic Solution (UNTESTED)

```
$args = array ('headers' => array(
    'Authentication' => 'xxx@dxwxcxrp.com:hPhO4IXXXXXYM2zXXXXX' //YOU NEED TO ADAPT TO YOUR AUTHENTICATION (BASIC, AUTH2, etc)
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    )
);
$rawData = wp_remote_get('https://dxwxcxrp.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/search?jql=created>=startOfMonth()&key=DCHC01&startAt=1&maxResults=1&fields=id,key', $args);
$data = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $rawData ), true );

var_dump($data);
$startAt = $data['startAt'];
echo $startAt; //Should be 1
```